Switching between CAN bus termination?
I'm designing a CAN bus that I need to be able to swap between two different termination points at one end. The switch doesn't need to be usable during operation; I just need two available configurations.
I would like to be able to use a switch to control this, but I'm not experienced enough to know if this is possible. Failing this, I suspect I'll just have two plugs to swap between.
Am I breaking any rules? What kind of switch would you use? If not a switch, what would you do? Thankyou :)

Do the answers in Add or remove 120 Ohm from the CAN circuit using Microcontroller help?

This question is similar to: Add or remove 120 Ohm from the CAN circuit using Microcontroller. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yep that's a duplicate. And as noted in my answer there it must be a fast analog switch. You can't use relays, SSR, plain MOSFETs etc.

I think this question is different: This one: a manually-operated switch. That one: a software controlled switch.
